# How can i use canActivate() to block access to certain routes?

Tags: angular, routes, auth-guard, canactivate

I am actually working on an website that have multiple users. I want to update a user's information and it works so fine but when i type on the URL an id of another user instead of the current user i can simply access to that profile while i am not supposed to .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a service to manage the current user logged in, it is possible to just compare both the ID in the URL and the current user ID. Let's say you have a service called AuthenticatedUserService which contains the logged in user details. You can just fetch the ID present in the route you're trying to access and compare both.

```
@Injectable()
class IsUserAllowed implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private currentUser: AuthenticatedUserService) {}

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean|UrlTree>|Promise<boolean|UrlTree>|boolean|UrlTree {
    const idInUrl = route.paramMap.get('id');
    return this.currentUser.getId() === idInUrl;
  }
}
```